# Removing vertical space before chapter headings.

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I have a problem that I can't seem to solve. Basically, I want my chapter headings to be at the same position relative to top of the page as the rest of the text. I've looked at numerous resources online, but the problem is still not solved... :(

I tried using the `titlesec` package, but no results:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thechapter}{1em}{\Large}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}
```

Here is what I get in the output:

Chapter Heading:

[image: chapter heading]

Other text (sections):

[image: section heding]

Also, the headings of TOC LoF and LoT are a little off from normal Chapter heading spacing...

Please help!

Comment: please identify the document class you are using.

Comment: @barbara beeton Sorry, I should've mentioned it initially. I am using the report doc class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is unfortunately not possible without redefining some internals of `titlesec`.  It uses the command

```
\vspace*{<before vspace>}
```

before the chapter command. This is an absolute distance even after a page break. Before sections headers it uses

```
\addvspace{<before vspace>}
```

There are a lot of rules regarding `\addvspace`, such as adding only the maximum of two sequencial `\addvspace`'s, no spacing after a page break, etc.

To get what you are asking for you can try the following redefinition

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\def\ttl@mkchap@i#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
    \ttl@assign\@tempskipa#3\relax\beforetitleunit
    \vspace{\@tempskipa}%<<<<<< REMOVE THE * AFTER \vspace
    \global\@afterindenttrue
    \ifcase#5 \global\@afterindentfalse\fi
    \ttl@assign\@tempskipb#4\relax\aftertitleunit
    \ttl@topmode{\@tempskipb}{%
        \ttl@select{#6}{#1}{#2}{#7}}%
    \ttl@finmarks  % Outside the box!
    \@ifundefined{ttlp@#6}{}{\ttlp@write{#6}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This is excellent, that you very much for your help! I still have a lot to lean in LaTeX :)

Answer (score 6):

in most document classes, the chapter heading starts with `\vspace*{<sink amount>}`.
in the report class, this is the first part of the definitions `\@makechapterhead` (for
numbered chapters) and `\@makeschapterhead` (for unnumbered chapters).

since the `titlesec` package apparently doesn't have a straightforward way to omit
this space, it seems easier to redefine the two relevant commands from `report.cls`.
just copy the two definitions into your preamble, comment out the unwanted `\vspace`
lines, wrap the whole block between `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` and go on your
way.  put in a comment to say why you did what you did; you'll be glad for this later.