# Make the "Appendix X" text go higher in report class

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, appendices, report

I have an appendix which goes 3 lines on a second page, so I would like to recover some "lost" space by the "Appendix" text on the top to keep it on one page.

I tried using `\vspace{some negative value}` or the titlesec package between `\appendix` and `\chapter`, but nothing moved...

My appendices looks like this :

```
\appendix
\chapter{Some code}
\label{cwalg}
\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17338/31058

Comment: I tried doing this when adding the big code part to the preamble of the document : `\appendix
\vspace*{-3}
\chapter{Some code}` but it doesn't work unfortunately. Am I wrong somewhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before the `\chapter` for the appendix add some changes to the spacing using `titlesec`'s `\titlespacing*` (in the example I changed the default `50pt` and used `-20pt` instead); the change will have effect only if you also use `\titleformat`, so I used the default definition:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A regular chapter}
\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{-20pt}{40pt}
\chapter{An appendix}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, define a new \@makechapterhead for Appendix right before the chapter for the appendix. One may change the distance via `\\`[xx]

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A First Chapter}
\chapter{A Second Chapter}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{ \null
\begin{flushleft} 
\huge\bfseries APPENDIX \thechapter\\
   #1
\end{flushleft}
\nobreak
}
\makeatletter
\appendix

\chapter{An appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]