# How to get rid of empty space

Tags: spacing

I'm just started using LaTeX, and I ran into a problem: The text starts way down in the page, so there is a lot of empty room. How do I move the text upwards?

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}    

\title{THT310}
\author{Eivind Hagen}  

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\thechapter.\ }

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}    

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\newpage    

\chapter{Introduksjon}
\input{kapittel1}
\chapter{del 2}
\input{kapittel2}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please do not paste code as images, but as code. -  [How to decrease spacing before chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63393/124842) could be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [How to decrease spacing before chapter title?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63390/5764); [Removing vertical space before chapter headings.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17299/5764)